# Laravel - Unable to run artisan command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

today I opened an old project from Laravel 5.4 (I think) and I wanted to just edit it a bit so I srt it all up but when running any artisan command I received a huge error that is written on the console (cmd).

```
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Create The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The first thing we will do is create a new Laravel application instance
| which serves as the "glue" for all the components of Laravel, and is
| the IoC container for the system binding all of the various parts.
|
*/

$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Bind Important Interfaces
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, we need to bind some important interfaces into the container so
| we will be able to resolve them when needed. The kernels serve the
| incoming requests to this application from both the web and CLI.
|
*/

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);

$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Return The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This script returns the application instance. The instance is given to
| the calling script so we can separate the building of the instances
| from the actual running of the application and sending responses.
|
*/

return $app;
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function make() on integer in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\mywebsite\website\artisan:31
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\mywebsite\website\artisan on line 31
```

It looks like the whole content of a php file then the error below

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function make() on integer in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\mywebsite\website\artisan:31
    Stack trace:
    #0 {main}
      thrown in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\mywebsite\website\artisan on line 31
```

Comment: Larvavel 5.4 doesn't exit.

Comment: Irrelevant comment, Like I said I wasn't sure.

Comment: Most importantly - why do you have the contents of the error in your bootstrap file? Get that out of there.

Comment: It seems you are having with a problem in ur Laravel files. you may have updated the version. the latest laravel is 5.3

Comment: I don't, I just pasted what was printed on my console, that isn't my actual bootstrap file..

Comment: Try this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/call-to-a-member-function-make-on-null

Comment: That is a totally different issue than I am having, plus I already tried the answers and none of them work.

Comment: It sounds to me like you haven't run `composer update` or `composer install`. Can you confirm you have a vendor folder and that this file exists? `Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class`.

Comment: @JaredEitnier Yes the kernel class exists.

Comment: Try to delete your vendor folder and run another `composer install` or `composer update`. Have you tried to debug the artisan script yet to see why it's failing?

Comment: When ever I run composer install it just ends with the same issue, displaying php content then the error.

Comment: Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function make() on integer

Comment: The error message tells you _exactly_ where the problem is: line 31 of the **artisan** file. So what’s there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP came into the php chatroom seeking help. After some debugging it turned out the issue was the application not being build correctly due to a missing `.env` file.

In the OP's case the issue was solved by renaming `_env` to `.env` and making sure the `APP_KEY` was set to a valid length and content.

Answer (score 1):

I just have this kind of error, then I found out that some of my files were corrupted specifically bootstrap/app.php that why it showing some weird characters.